# Facebook "OR" queries with the graph API

Tags: facebook, search, graph

Searching for "OR" queries on facebook is an exercise in futility as "OR" gets filtered.

Cannot find a way to search for " X or Y or Z "

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=cats%20OR%20Dogs&type=post

Results in it only finding posts which contains both Cats and Dogs:

```
{
     "id": "100000895865837_129212313793038",
     "from": {
        "name": "Faxon LeCat",
        "id": "100000895865837"
     },
     "message": "Over and over again I see dogs or cats who are \"owner surrenders\" for one reason or another. When you get a pet - it's for life! They are not toys to be returned when you tire of them!",
     "type": "status",
     "created_time": "2010-09-06T22:48:33+0000",
     "updated_time": "2010-09-07T00:32:43+0000",
     "likes": 12
  }
```

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=cats%20Dogs&type=post

results in:

```
 {
     "id": "100000573125293_144875485549138",
     "from": {
        "name": "Gianna Fedullo",
        "id": "100000573125293"
     },
     "message": "Dogs and cats are enimies, but yah know the dogs alwaaays winn(; FMS<3 .",
     "type": "status",
     "created_time": "2010-09-07T00:38:23+0000",
     "updated_time": "2010-09-07T00:38:23+0000"
  }
```

Anyone know the magic invocation that lets it search "OR" ?

Have tried " 'x' or 'y' ", "x|y", "x y", "x,y" etc....

Comment: easy. first you search for cats then you search for dogs and finaly you combine serach results. ta da

Answer (score 2):

Indeed using OR doesn't work. However using a pipe (|) does:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=cats%20|%20Dogs&type=post

Cheers,
Boaz

Comment: You made my day ! Where did you get this info ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that | is not working anymore. I've posted ne question about thet [Facebook Graph API search with OR statments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765416/facebook-graph-api-search-with-or-statments).

Comment: Is there a workaround to this issue? Wondering if facebook allows using "OR" operand in the queries?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried || (double pipe) or capital "OR"?