# Facebook Graph API search with OR statments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on an applications which use facebook Grap API for search. We quite often query facebook with OR queries (using | [Facebook "OR" queries with the graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655077/facebook-or-queries-with-the-graph-api)). But it seems that it just stopped working. Does anyone know if it is still possible to perform OR queries with Graph API search method, and if so how to do it?

Comment: In FQL? Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem. I made some "googling" and found this out: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/120122231487168?browse=search_50d089ba103283049766070

It seems the pipe "|" is no long supported. "This is by design", as they say.